# How to initialize an object with known parameters that is a member of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, c++14, class-members

I have the following class:

```
class Counter {
private:
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int inc_by;

public:
    Counter(unsigned int count, unsigned int inc_by) : count(count), inc_by(inc_by) {}

    void increment() {
        count += inc_by;
    }
};
```

I think have another class `Timer` where I want to use the `Counter` object in. However, I want every instance of `Timer` to have a `Counter` object private member that is initialized with known parameters. I also can not use dynamic memory allocation.

I have tried the following:

```
class Timer {
private:
    Counter counter(0, 1);

public:
    Timer() {}
};
```

This results in the compiler error `Function 'counter' is not implemented`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Counter counter(0, 1);` is vexing parse.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
Counter counter { 0, 1 };
```

You may use only the so-called brace-or-equal-initializers.

Or you could initialize the data member in the constructor like

```
Timer() : counter( 0, 1 ){}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only [two ways](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) you can initialize non-static data members.

If you want to give an initial value to a member where it's declared, you need `{}`, like this:

```
Counter counter {0, 1};
```

Otherwise, you can define the initial value in the member initializer list of `Timer`'s constructor, like this:

```
Timer() : counter(0,1) {}
```